# Distance from one point to multiple points WITHIN a shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, distance, measurements, rivers

I am looking to calculate the distance from a main point to multiple points WITHIN shapefile. 
In other words: I have a main point at the mouth of a creek. I have about 1,200 points at various distances upstream from the mouth. I would like to calculate the distance from the mouth to each individual point. (aka, mouth to point 1, mouth to point 2, mouth to point 3, etc.) So, in the end, I would end up with 1,200 measurements, all starting at the mouth of the creek. 
I can only find tools that measure Euclidean distance or measure distance BETWEEN two consecutive points along a line, which will not work. I am looking for something that measures distance ALONG the route of the creek from one main point to multiple other points.
Any tips?

Screenshot image: want to find individual measurements from mouth point (red) to each blue point.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.3.1. I have no experience with Python.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use [Point Distance tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/point-distance.htm): create a new feature class with just mouth point. and other points as a near features.
2. to calculte distance along a line, Use Linear referencing.
   First convert the polylines to routes using the Create Routes tool, and then use the Locate Features Along Routes tool to write the route and measure information to a new event table.

[Creating routes using a tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/linear-referencing/create-routes.htm)

[Locating point features along routes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/linear-referencing/locating-features-along-routes-about-locating-feat.htm)

Comment: Okay. I may be missing something, but it looks like that only measures linear/euclidean distance. That is the issue I'm running into - cannot find something that measures distance in this manner ALONG a line shapefile. I've tried locate features along routes tool, though having issues with that too.

Comment: I edited my answer. Hope this help you